# Is there a definition of a translation from propositional logic to first order logic?

Tags: propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I want to know if there is a universally applicable definition of a translation from
propositional logic to first-order logic. I'm able to translate almost any propositional formula to a first-order logic by defining first-order functions with quantifiers, variables and constant, but i did not found any definition of a translation in my books..

So is there such a definition of a translation?
Thank you...

Answer (score 3):

Hold on ....

Many (most?) standard versions of FOL have either (i) a separate class of propositional letters as well as predicate letters, or (ii) allow zero-adic predicates, i.e. predicates that take zero terms to form a wff, and so are in effect acting as propositional letters.

Either way, a PL wff can then just be rendered directly into a corresponding FOL wff (with some change of alphabet perhaps) without using any quantifiers variables  or individual constants.

If you are using a textbook which as it happens doesn't build in propositional letters/zero-adic predicates to its version of the language of FOL, then adding them is a trivial variation of no real significance.

Comment: Can you give me an example of an FOL wff without any quantifiers or constants?
E.g. P $\land$ Q
Where P stands for = dog in house and
Q = Luca is Sandras boyfriend

My translation would be:

$\exists x(d(x) \land h(x, b(s)))$
Where d(x) = x is a dog, h(x,y), x is in house of y, b(x) = boyfriend of x and s = sandra as a constant